# Viewing git filters output when using meld as a diff tool

Tags: git, filter, diff, meld

I set up some [git filters](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) in order to preprocess certain files (in my case IPython Notebooks) before committing them. To be more exact I'm following these instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844506/578770

This works fine and the files are correctly filtered if I commit my changes or if I review the change using the command line "git diff ".

However, if I'm reviewing my changes using meld, the files are not filtered.
I tried several way to set up meld as a diff tool for git:

- by calling git difftool
- by calling meld from [a custom script](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2011/05/03/using-meld-with-git-diff/)

But none of the solutions I've found for using meld as a diff tool enables me to view the change of the file after the git filters is applied.

Anybody has an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack solution for this problem. The original git filter you are referring to has been formalized as the package `nbstripout` (`pip3 install nbstripout`), but you could put any filter into this script and it would work the same. I'll assume you want to configure this for the user rather than a particular repo.

In `~/.gitconfig`, add a new diff driver named `git-nb-clean-diff`:

```
[diff "git-nb-clean-diff"]
    command = git-nb-clean-diff
```

In `~/.config/git/attributes`, configure notebooks to be diffed with that diff driver:

```
*.ipynb diff=git-nb-clean-diff
```

Now we need to make the actual diff driver! In `~/bin/git-nb-clean-diff` (must have this filename but the location is optional):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# pass the stripped working tree file and the repo copy 
# to meld for diffing
meld <(cat $1 | nbstripout) $2
```

Lastly, we make this file executable

```
chmod +x ~/bin/git-nb-clean-diff
```

and add it to the path so git can find our diff driver when it runs

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
# reload the edited .bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank for your help, using a git-driver was the solution!
Concerning the notebook filter, I started using the nbdime packages (http://nbdime.readthedocs.io) instead of nbstripout. It provides a browser interface for diffing the notebook with the pictures.

Comment: You're welcome! Are you using nbdime's output filtering as well, or still storing the outputs?

Comment: I'm storing/commiting the outputs now. This way I can still see the same plots on all my devices but I do not have ugly diff.

Comment: Hi, before opening another question, I would like to know if this procedure is still working with the latest nbstripout and meld. I can't make it working, but I am also keeping some default configurations of nbstripout like 
`[filter "nbstripout"]
     clean = \"/home/me/anaconda3/bin/python3.8\" -m nbstripout
     smudge = cat
    [diff "ipynb"]
     textconv = \"/home/me/anaconda3/bin/python3.8\" -m nbstripout -t` and an attribute file 
`*.ipynb filter=nbstripout
*.ipynb diff=ipynb`.